# How to check for partial anagram in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thank you so much for looking at this question.

I am really stuck on a particular question, I shall post the question below:

Define a function partial anagram (str1, str2), which returns `True` if every letter that
occurs in str1 occurs at least as many times in `str2`, otherwise it returns False.

(Note: there may be additional letters in `str2` which do not occur in str1, which is why str1 is only a partial anagram of `str2`.) [4 marks]

Hint: If you convert `str2` into a list, you can then loop over the characters in str1 checking that each is present in `str2`. If it is not present then str1 cannot be a partial anagram of `str2` (so return `False`). If it is present you need to remove that character from the list (since it has been used up) and then carry on looping. If you loop through all the characters in str1 and always and a match in `str2`, then you can return True.

This is my code:

```
def partial_anagram(str1,str2):
    str2_list = list(str2)
    for char in str1:
        if char in str2_list:
            str2_list.remove(char)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Why do you have `return str2_list` within the for loop? Your requirements say you should only return `True` or `False`.

Comment: This looks like an interesting problem, but what is the intended use of this function?

Answer (score 0):

Your only error seems to be early return in your function. While your **hint** proposes `then carry on looping`, by issuing `return` statement you end your function and return `True`. Your code, slightly modified, seems correct to me:

```
def partial_anagram(str1, str2):
    str2_list = list(str2)
    for char in str1:
        if char in str2_list:
            str2_list.remove(char)
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

But I don't really like hints and proposed way of solution in your assignment. As for me, I would solve this task other way:

```
from collections import Counter

def partial_anagram_counter(a, b):
    if Counter(a) - Counter(b):
         return False
    return True

>>> partial_anagram_counter('abacaba','aabbaaccaabbaa')
True
>>> partial_anagram('abacaba','aabbaaccaabbaa')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then this should be what you want:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def partial_anagram(str1, str2):
...     return not bool(Counter(str1)-Counter(str2))
...
>>> partial_anagram('abc', 'abc')
True
>>> partial_anagram('abc', 'cba')
True
>>> partial_anagram('abc', 'cb')
False
>>> partial_anagram('abac', 'cba')
False
>>> partial_anagram('abac', 'acbad')
True
>>>
```

---

Note that the above solution uses a special tool known as [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  However, if you are not allowed to use this class, then you can do this:

```
>>> def partial_anagram(str1, str2):
...     return all(str2.count(x) >= str1.count(x) for x in set(str1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that something like this would suffice:

```
def partial_anagram(str1, str2):
    return not False in [str1.count(x) <= str2.count(x) for x in str1]
```

This generates a list that, for each character in `str1`, is a boolean indicating whether `str2` contains at least as many of that character as `str1`. If `False` appears in that list, then at least one character in `str1` occurs more times than in `str2`.

It could possibly be a little more efficient by not checking each duplicate character, but as long as your strings are relatively small, the gain in efficiency would probably not be worth the additional code. The answer by @iCodez employs that optimization via the `Counter` class, and may be more efficient for larger strings.

Comment: Doing `for x in set(str1)` will stop the duplicate checking.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead you have a variable with an initial value of 0. Then in that for loop, when ever `str2` has a character that is in `str1`, you can increment this variable.

At the end, if the variable has a value equal to the length of `str1`, then you know that `str2` contains all the characters in `str1`.

```
def partial_anagram(str1,str2):
    b=0
    str2_list = list(str2)
    for char in str1:
        if char in str2_list:
            str2_list.remove(char)
            b+=1
    if b==len(str1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You could use this to check for a full anagram as well. If `b` is  equal to the length of `str2` as well as `str1`, then `str1` and `str2` will have exactly the same characters, which you should be able to write by your self (just add `and b==len(str2)` in that final if-statement).